# Who is going around downvoting answers that were beta, pre-comment?

Tags: discussion, down-votes

Just wondering :)

For example, here: [Best way to test if a generic type is a string? (c#)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31498/best-way-to-test-if-a-generic-type-is-a-string-c/31531#31531)

Comment: Do you have a problem with losing a meager two rep points per unsuitable "answer" as a gentle reminder that there are some posts that should either be reincorporated on the question or as comments now that you are over 35k?

Comment: @voyager just curious. I usually leave comments myself unless the answer has harmful or blatantly wrong information about the central topic.

Comment: There was a pre-comments? In the long long ago? Wow. How did you manage?

Comment: @Questions: They used answers. (Did you read the question? :P )

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It wasn't me, but people *did* leave you comments over a year ago telling you it wasn't really appropriate anymore. The best course of action would have been to delete it and, if necessary, put it in a comment or edit it into the question. Just because it's old doesn't mean it can't be updated to fit with the current site standards.

Comment: That's fair. I've generally felt averse to making major structural changes to a conversation that is "complete" but your articulation makes it sound more palatable than I was imagining.

Answer (score 1):

I think it's a good thing.

It calls to your attention your old posts so you can delete them and repost them as comments (which you didn't, but you went through all the trouble of going to meta to post about it for some reason).

PS: why the random CW?

Comment: -1 because causing noise on old questions is pointless.

Comment: I don't want rep considerations on a discussion about rep

Comment: @Earlz: It's not adding noise, it's taking it away.

Comment: @Rex It's meta. The rep here is about as useful as lottery scrathers

Comment: @Earlz: huh? Old questions don't dust away, heh. They are as useful as new ones.

Comment: @gnov no it's adding a ton of out of date comments on questions which though it doesn't bump it to the front page, it does notify the asker

Comment: @Earlz: The extra notifications are a small price to pay for a cleaner and easier to follow set of answers and comments.